# Toggle background video to background color

Tags: jquery, css, html, video, background

So the problem is that I need to have a link, which leads to turning background video into a background color(or to fallback image) and vice versa.

My video is made visible thanks to HTML5

```
    <video autoplay loop poster="img/fallback.png" muted="muted" id="bgvid">
        <source src="bg.webm" type="video/webm">
        <source src="bg.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
```

The link should change the background video to a plain color or image. Link on click changes its content as well.

Comment: it is easy with jquery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by fading the video out to show the background color with jQuery :

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/4VR5f/)**

*HTML :*

```
<video autoplay loop poster="img/fallback.png" muted="muted" id="bgvid">
    <source src="bg.webm" type="video/webm">
        <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/tags/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
<button type="button">Give me color</button>
<button id="vid" type="button">Give me video</button>
```

*jQuery :*

```
$('button').click(function () {
    $('video').fadeToggle(500);
    $('button').fadeToggle(500);
});
```

*CSS :*

```
body {
    background:gold;
    margin:0;
}
video {
    min-width:100%;
    min-height:100%;
    width:auto;
    height:auto;
}
button {
    position:absolute;
    top:10%;
    left:10%;
}
#vid {
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks web-tiki, you def made my day! Indeed, as Alex commented, it's easy with jquery. Except there is visual defect on click.. Please see http://jsfiddle.net/4VR5f/12/ I have updated with my content. is there any way to get around bug(which it is in my case) that on click blank row is visible, therefore menu "jumps" vertically.

Comment: wow, amazing, Im diving in! I was refreshing like crazy. thank you very much for quick response.

Comment: dumb I.. had to know it myself. thanks again. will try to think more myself than waiting... creative css!